# return a computed field in a serialized django object?

Tags: serialization, django-models

I'm writing an API using Django, and I'm running into some issues around returning data that isn't stored in the database directly, or in other cases organized differently than the database schema.

In particular, given a particular data request, I want to add a field of computed data to my model before I serialize and return it. However, if I just add the field to the model, the built-in serializer (I'm using json) ignores it, presumably because it's getting the list of fields from the model definition.

I could write my own serializer, but what a pain. Or I guess I could run model_to_dict, then serialize the dict instead of the model. Anyone have any better ideas?

Here's what the code vaguely looks like right now:

```
squidlets = Squidlet.objects.filter(stuff)
for i in range(len(squidlets)):
    squidlets[i].newfield = do_some_computation(squid)
return HttpResponse(json_serializer.serialize(squidlets,ensure_ascii=False),
                    'text/json')
```

But newfield ain't in the returned json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the dict solution, which turned out to be fairly clean.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

squiddicts = []
squidlets = Squidlet.objects.filter(stuff)
for i in range(len(squidlets)):
    squiddict = model_to_dict(squidlets[i])
    squiddict["newfield"] = do_some_computation(squidlets[i])
    squiddicts.append(squiddict)
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(squiddicts,ensure_ascii=False),
                    'text/json')
```

This is maybe slightly more verbose than necessary but I think it's clearer this way.

This does still feel somewhat unsatisfying, but seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should serialize using simple json..  and it doent have to be a queryset...  to escape it as json also use marksafe

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils import simplejson
simplejson.dumps(mark_safe(your_data_structure))
```

Comment: That doesn't work. If you just use simplejson.dumps on the objects, it throws an exception because a Squidlet object is not JSON serializable. If you use mark_safe(), for reasons I don't really understand it blows away all the inside the object before it serializes.

Comment: Here's what simplejson.dumps(mark_safe()) looks like: "[, , , ]"

Comment: Here's what my original code returns: [{"pk": 1, "model": "squid.squidlet", "fields": {"status": "Active", "group": 5, "contact_user": 2}}]